# How to get the file from FileUpload in GWT

Tags: mysql, gwt, file-upload

I'm working with GWT and have a FileUpload widget wrapped in a FormPanel along with a textbox and submit button.

I want to write the data to a MySQL database. I can successfully make a call to the server and insert the fileName, name, etc to the DB. But how do I upload the actual file to the database? I'm having a hard time understanding how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [Apache FileUpload library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) to parse the incoming file using a standard `HTTPServlet`.

If you're using just the MySQL java library, here's a code snippet on how to take the file stream from the upload and pass it to your MySQL code:

[java insert Blob as ByteArrayOutputStream get ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293828/java-insert-blob-as-bytearrayoutputstream-get-classcastexception)

Answer (score 0):

Generally the uploading in GWT works as in any J2E project with a Servlet. See example [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/file-upload-example-in-servlet-and-jsp.html)

However, I suggest using [GWTUpload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) which offers better features (MultiUploading, progress bar ...) and can be easily integrated.

Answer (score 0):

First read the file and store its content into a String variable, say `fileData`.

Then have a `BLOB`, `CLOB` or `TEXT` type column in your table and insert the `fileData` value into that column.

For more info on the data types mentioned above, have a look at these: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

[MySQL TEXT vs BLOB vs CLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071662/mysql-text-vs-blob-vs-clob)

Comment: I have the column defined by BLOB. But how do I "read the file"? That's what I can't figure out

Comment: @user3153897 Are you getting the whole file on server?